# Offset setting a limit?

Tags: entries, query, limit

If have this in a template:

```
{% for mainLink in section.links.limit(4).all() %}
{% endfor %}

{% for secondaryLink in section.links.offset(4).all() %}
{% endfor %}
```

Which I thought would show the first four in the first list and however many from 5 onwards in the secondary list. But what's happening is that the second list is limiting the output to 4 as well. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're setting `section.links.limit(4)`, Craft will persist that limit in subsequent calls.

This was a change introduced in Craft 3, which you can read about [Changes in Craft 3 | Cloning Element Queries](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#cloning-element-queries)

---

You have two options to resolve your issue:

Use `clone()` to create a new version of the `ElementCriteriaModel` for each time you use `section.links`

```
{% for mainLink in clone(section.links).limit(4).all() %}
{% endfor %}

{% for secondaryLink in clone(section.links).offset(4).all() %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or unset the limit your limit in the second for loop

```
{% for mainLink in section.links.limit(4).all() %}
{% endfor %}

{% for secondaryLink in section.links.limit(null).offset(4).all() %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Joshua M's answer explains why it's happening, but in terms of best practice, you'd be better off avoiding multiple roundtrips to the database by using Twig filters on a single result set. There are probably a few different ways, but here's one using `slice`:

```
{% set allLinks = section.links.all() %}

{% for link in allLinks|slice(0, 3) %}
    {# iterate through the first 4 items #}
{% endfor %}

{% for link in allLinks|slice(3) %}
    {# iterate from the 4th item to the last #}
{% endfor %}
```